# Binary and continuous variables in the same regression?

Tags: regression, least-squares, binary-data

How do you go about conducting a regression when you have 5 continuous and 3 binary variables?

Can you do it in one operation?

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=binary+continuous+regression

Answer (score 0):

yes you can conduct a regression, you just need to create dummy variables for binary variables and then you are all good in carrying that out in one operation.

Answer (score 0):

that depend on which variable is dependent variable. If the dependent variable is continuous, the operation of the regression is same as the common one. But if the dependent variable is binary, you should use logistic regression

Comment: Thank you for that comment, the dependent variable is continuous

Comment: I am sure a more detailed answer can be found in the thread that represents a duplicate for this question.